# How to map an Option inside a for comprehension with EitherT

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Hi I am trying to execute a for comprehension like

```
(for {
  player <- playerRepository.findById(playerId) // findById returns EitherT[Future, String, Player]
  teamOpt <- teamRepository.findByPlayer(playerId) // findByPlayer returns EitherT[Future, String, Option[Team]]
  playedMatches <- teamOpt.map(team => playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id)) // findByTeamId returns EitherT[Future, String, Seq[PlayedMatches]]
} yield (
  player,
  teamOpt,
  playedMatches
)).fold(
  error => {
    logger.error(s"all error: $error")
    Left(error)
  },
  tuple => {
    logger.debug(s"get success -> $tuple")
    Right(playerDetailResponse(tuple._1, tuple._2, tuple._3))
  }
)
```

I can not get a corret structure for

```
playedMatches <- teamOpt.map(team => playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id))
```

I am getting the following error when I compile the project

```
[error] /Users/agusgambina/code/soccer/app/services/impl/PlayerServiceImpl.scala:28:17: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Option[(models.Player, Option[models.Team], cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,String,Seq[models.PlayedMatches]])]
[error]  required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,?,?]
[error]       playedMatches <- teamOpt.map(team => playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id))
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
```

I tried to wrap

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: What is `teamOpt.map(team => ...` supposed to be? `Seq[Either]`?

Comment: You may need to include more of your code. What does `playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id)` return? If it is also returning an Option you may want to be using `flatMap` instead of `map.`

Comment: @ElBaulP thank you for the comment, I updated the question

Comment: @BlueSheepToken thank you for the comment. If teamOpt is not null it should retrieve a EitherT[Future, String, Seq[PlayedMatches]], other case it should be None

Comment: @codenoodle thank you for the comment.thank you I will clarify that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
playedMatches <- teamOpt.map(team => playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id)) // findByTeamId returns EitherT[Future, String, Seq[PlayedMatches]]
```

in here, you are getting an Option[EitherT[Future, String, Seq[PlayedMatches]]] which doesn't compose with the EitherT[Future, String, ???] you are using as Monad for the for comprehension.

one option you have is to actually use a fold on teamOpt.

```
teamOpt.fold(EitherT(Future.successful(Left("Team not Found"): Either[String, Team]))){ team => playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id) }
```

This way you unwrap the Option with the error case if is empty or the success case if non-empty. (create a function that takes the teamOPt as parameter and the for-comprehension will look much better)

Hope it helps

**update**
In case of the empty case be successful, and be happy returning an empty sequence:

```
teamOpt.fold(
  EitherT(Future.successful(Right(Seq()): Either[String, Seq[PlayedMatches]))
){ team =>
  playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @FerranJr I think that with your help I am really close. The only thing I am trying to figure out is. If the team is None, the playedMatches should be None also (it should not be an error).

Comment: Using fold you are not force to convert the empty case in an error, it can be the case of you being ok with it...

If playedMatches is a Seq then you could return an empty sequence on the empty case:

teamOpt.fold(EitherT(Future.successful(Right(Seq.empty[PlayedMatches]): Either[String, Seq[PlayedMatches]]))){ team => playedMatchesRepository.findByTeamId(team.id) }

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It helped me to understand and it is also working.

Comment: I'm glad it helped